# Get the return type of begin on a c array

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator, decltype

I would like to get the return type of `std::begin` in a generic way. My current solution is:

```
using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()));
```

and it works when `T = std::vector<int>`. But I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<int[3]>()));
```

I get the error:

```
example.cpp:83:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int [3])’
     using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<int[3]>()));
```

How to get the return type of `std::begin` in a generic way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overload for [arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) is:

```
template< class T, std::size_t N > 
constexpr T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```

And `std::declval<int[3]>()` gives you a `int(&&)[3]`, which doesn't match that overload. It also doesn't match the normal container overload, because those are SFINAE-ed on having `c.begin()`. So you're left with no matching function.

What you need instead is to pass an *lvalue* reference to array to `begin()`, to get the iterator back out. So either you need to manually provide a that lvalue reference when you use your alias:

```
template <class T>
using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()));

using arr = type<int(&)[3]>; // int*
```

or have the alias itself provide the lvalue reference for you:

```
template <class T>
using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>()));

using arr = type<int[3]>; // int*
```

The former seems more correct to me, but YMMV.